# How can I get the Typescript type in these sample codes?

Tags: typescript

First, I declare two interface in Typescript

```js
interface A {
    type: 'a',
    option: {
        key: string
        value: any
    }
}

interface B {
    type: 'b' | 'c',
    option: {
        key: string
        secondKey: string
        value: any
        secondValue: any
    }
}
```

Next I declare one variable use the interfaces

```js
const foo: (A | B)[] = [
    {
        type: 'a',
        option: {
            key: 'keyOfA',
            value: 'valueOfA'
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'b',
        option: {
            key: 'keyOfB',
            value: 'valueOfB',
            secondKey: 'secondKeyOfB',
            secondValue: 'secondValueOfB' 
        }
    }
]
```

When the function returns, I want to get a TypeScript type like {keyOfA: valueOfA, keyOfB: valueOfB, secondKeyOfB: secondValueOfB}.

```js
// type test = ??
// const a = fooFunc(foo)
function fooFunc<T extends (A | B)[]>(foo: T): test {
    foo.reduce((prev, cur) => {
        if(cur.type === 'a') {
            return {
                ...prev,
                [cur.option.key]: cur.option.value
            }
        } else {
            return {
                ...prev,
                [cur.option.key]: cur.option.value,
                [cur.option.secondKey]: cur.option.secondValue,
            }
        }
        
    }, {})
}
```

The code above is my only question. I would be extremely grateful if you could help me resolve it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Functions return at runtime. TypeScript types only exist at compile time. JavaScript has no access to the type information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think what you want is not possible in TypeScript. You're trying to add object properties whose property names are based on runtime values, which is just not possible to type-infer.

Comment: Thanks,I have a better understanding of where my problem lies. I've always known that TypeScript can only perform static type checking, but I often see people converting TypeScript types into another type. So I was wondering if it's possible to extract certain values from generics in order to provide a better development experience within functions.